# setar item da JComboBox

Tags: java, jcombobox

Eu tenho duas JComboBox, as duas contém strings referentes a nomes de compradores e produtos. Preciso que ao clickar na tabela eu possa setar as JComboBox com os nomes.

Vi nesse fórum dois exemplos de códigos mas os mesmos não funcionam por isso estou fazendo a pergunta ... abaixo são as linhas que não funcionam

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora segue meu código.

```
public TelaAdicionarVenda() {
        try {
            ConexaoBancoDados.VendaDAO.criarTabela();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TelaAdicionarVenda.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Falha ao criar tabela de venda" + ex);
        }
        initComponents();
        try {
            List<String> listaNomesCompradores= ConexaoBancoDados.ClienteDAO.carregarNomeClientes();
            for (String comprador : listaNomesCompradores){
                comprador_CBox.add(comprador);
            }
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException | ConnectException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TelaAdicionarVenda.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Falha ao carregar clientes" + ex);
        }
        List<String> listaNomesProdutos= ConexaoBancoDados.ProdutoDAO.carregarNomeProdutos();
        for (String produto : listaNomesProdutos){
            produto_CBox.add(produto);
        }
        try {
            atualizarTabela();
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException | ConnectException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TelaAdicionarVenda.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Falha na atualização da tabela");
        } 

    }
private void tabelaVendasMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
    int row = tabelaVendas.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
    strQuantidade.setText(tabelaVendas.getModel().getValueAt(row, 3).toString());
    strValorTotal.setText(tabelaVendas.getModel().getValueAt(row, 4).toString());
    strValorPago.setText(tabelaVendas.getModel().getValueAt(row, 5).toString());
    strDataVenda.setText(tabelaVendas.getModel().getValueAt(row, 6).toString());
    strDataQuitacao.setText(tabelaVendas.getModel().getValueAt(row, 7).toString());
    this.idVenda=(int) tabelaVendas.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0);
    comprador_CBox.setSelectedItem(tabelaVendas.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1).toString());
    produto_CBox.getModel().setSelectedItem(tabelaVendas.getModel().getValueAt(row, 2).toString());
}
```

Comment: Adicione um codigo que seja testavel, na forma de um **[mcve]**

Comment: Se seu `produto_CBox` é um objeto `JComboBox` tente tirar o `.getModel()`

Comment: Na imagem que eu postei tem o código repetido, um com getmodel outro sem.
Infelizmente não é isso.
Obrigado pela ajuda.